# Dropbox API - Share folder and contents in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

Using the Dropbox API I can share or get a direct link to a folder. I can also share or get a direct link to any file inside that folder.

I'm trying to create my own container for the folder on my app. The users should be able to open the files of the folder. The problem is that if I just share the folder the link Dropbox provides shows their folder container, and the files inside are displayed in their container. I can get direct links for each of the files and make my own list of files in my container but it is not very efficient since I have to get links separately for each file in the folder.

Is it possible to share the folder -- or get direct url -- and automatically be able to access the files it contains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want the /media API call

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media

To quote "Similar to /shares. The difference is that this bypasses the Dropbox webserver, used to provide a preview of the file, so that you can effectively stream the contents of your media."

Comment: Just in time since I'm back to this project again. I'll accept the answer when I try it out. Thanks!