# Get links to files inside of shared folder?

Tags: dropbox-api

I am developing a web-app using the Dropbox Core API. As a part of functionality of the app, it needs to download specific files from a shared folder.

I have used the [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) endpoint to get a shared link for the folder. But given the shared link to a folder, is there a way to programatically download a specific file within that folder?

I already know you can download the whole folder as zip by appending dl=1. But I'm looking to get individual files.

My question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054337/dropbox-api-share-folder-and-contents-in-it), but using the [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) enpoint does not return links that are persistent.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To answer your question, no. But could you describe why you need this? If you're using the Core API, can't you just download the files directly or create more share links?

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that. The registered users of the app would have the ability to create teams, so I need the authorized users to be able to access files in a particular folder in each other's app directory.

Comment: [I work on this project with Jay] Clarifying one point: It's not important that there be any authorization. It is acceptable (perhaps even preferred) for all files and folders to be world readable.